# I'm trying to get rid of garbage lines in a file

Tags: python

I've tried slicing the lists in the file but it still doesn't come back with correct line count which should be 4051.

My code:

```
def readData(filename):

    inputFile = open(filename, 'r')
    inputFile.readline()
    playerList = []

    for line in inputFile:
        fields = line.split(",")
        playerList.append(fields[1:4052])

    inputFile.close()

    return playerList
```

Comment: Please define "garbage line"

Comment: I think you should use readlines() instead of readline()

Comment: you read lines but you don't skip any line - you only split every line in fields with 4051 columns (not lines/rows)

Comment: @YukunLi That will read the entire file, and there won't be anything left for the `for line in inputFile:` loop to read.

Comment: @YukunLi I think OP uses `readline()`  to skip first line with headers.

Comment: `fields[1:4052]` is slicing the fields on one line, it's not slicing the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

`fields[1:4052]` slices the fields on each line, it doesn't slice the lines in the file.

If you only want the first 4051 lines of the file, use `range(4051)` to read the lines.

```
def readData(filename):
    playerList = []
    with inputFile as open(filename):
        inputFile.readline() # skip headers
        for _ in range(4051):
            line = inputFile.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            fields = line.split(",")
            playerList.append(fields)
    return playerList
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that 4051 wasn't magical, the OP merely was concerned that the read results didn't match what they knew the line count to be, here's a more concise version (might also suggest read_players as a possibly more descriptive function name):

```
def readData(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputFile:
        inputFile.readline() # skip headers
        playerList = [line.strip().split(',') for line in inputFile]
    return playerList
```